# Displaying data through std Class Object and Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wsdl

I am having trouble in displaying data through std Class Object and Array in PHP. Basically I have fetched data from .wsdl file through a web service. 
Below is the screenshot of some data. Kindly go through this screenshot.

[image]

I am trying to display items:

1. Ldate
2. Ltime
3. Satza

For this I am using:

```
foreach($data as $objects){
echo $objects->Itab->item[0]->Ldate;}
```

Here `$data` is an object which contains all values fetched from .wsdl file. I don't understand where I am doing wrong.
Kindly tell me a way by which I can display these three values (Ldate, Ltime, Satza) in a loop.

Comment: what is the error or warning ?

Comment: Is `$data` really an array so you need to `foreach` it? From screenshot, i would guess you need to catch your data with `foreach($data->Itab->item as $values)` and then get `$values->Ldate`, `$values->Ltime` etc...

Comment: Thank you Bojan Radaković for your response. Issue is resolved. It was a mistake in the loop. 
Thanks again :)